# Build child module without building parent module if there is some changes in parent pom

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have a multi module project with more than 70 modules and it takes 3 Hrs to build the project with tests.

Parent pom.xml

```
 ...
   <version>${revision}</version>
   <properties>
      <app.version>1.0</app.version
   <properties>
   .....
   <modules>
     <module>a<module>
     <module>b<module>
     <module>c<module>
   .....
 ...
```

Child pom.xml

```
 <parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>${revision}</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>b</artifactId>
```

How to build only module b only if we change the version number in parent pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading the parent POM to a new version (and the reference to it in `b`'s `pom.xml`), you could run :

```
mvn --projects b <maven_phase_you_want> # or mvn -pl b [...]
```

From Maven's help :

```
-pl,--projects <arg>                Comma-delimited list of specified
                                    reactor projects to build instead
                                    of all projects. A project can be
                                    specified by [groupId]:artifactId
                                    or by its relative path
```

However, this only works if the old version of your parent POM is already in your local repository, or at least is available (it have been deployed on a repository manager). Otherwise, you'll get an error because, even if specifying `--projects b`, Maven will try to resolve parent POM (that he won't find) for other modules `a` and `c`.